# In Asp.net mvc ,Jquery Datatable pagination lose or hide the dynamic dropdown on next page click or sorting the table or on search

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, dropdown

On asp.net mvc, loading data with the help of jquery ajax. In Form, using jquery datatable and binding some record and inside the table there are some record and dynamic html dropdowns inside table when i click on pagination next page on next page record bind but dropdowns not showing why. Please help my code and screenshot is below.

```
@model ITHAMMVC.BO.StockManagement.InventoryVerifyInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "InventoryVerify";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<main>`your text`
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="it-card">
            <div class="card-header tableFilterWarp">
                <h4 class="card-title">Inventory data verification</h4>
                <div class="form-group ds-autoComplete_Emp ds-input-with-icon">
                    <div id="employee-info" class="autoComplete_Emp input-icon">
                        <i class="i-icon icon-outline-search"></i>
                        <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search by model name or serial number" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Table with action link-->
            <div class="common_table line-tbl mt-16">
                <table id="withLine" class="table glb_datable inventory-data">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <div class="form-group ds-checkbox">
                                    <label class="checkbox-label" for="Model">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll1" id="Model">
                                        <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                                        <span class="inner-label"> Model </span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                            </th>
                            <th>Serial</th>
                            <th>Physical availability</th>
                            <th>Rack</th>
                            <th>Shelf</th>
                            <th>Physical condition</th>
                            <th>Remarks</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @foreach (var inventorydata in Model.inventoryInfos)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group ds-checkbox">
                                        <label class="checkbox-label" for="@inventorydata.TranId">
                                            @if (inventorydata.IsVerified == 1)
                                            {
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkedId" class="check1 chkInventoryVerification" value="1" checked="checked" id="@inventorydata.TranId">

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkedId" class="check1 chkInventoryVerification" value="1" id="@inventorydata.TranId">

                                            }

                                            <input type="hidden" name="hdnAssetId" value="@inventorydata.AssetId" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="hdnTranId" value="@inventorydata.TranId" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="hdnMacUserId" value="@inventorydata.MacUserId" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="hdnHygeineId" value="@inventorydata.HygeineId" />
                                            <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                                            <span class="inner-label"> @inventorydata.ModelName </span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>@inventorydata.SerialNumber</td>
                                <td>
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="store"></label>
                                    <select class="selectpicker" title="Select option" name="ddlphysicalctivity" id="ddlpa_@inventorydata.TranId">
                                        @foreach (var physicalAvailibility in Model.physicalAvailibilities)
                                        {
                                            if (@inventorydata.PAId != 0)
                                            {
                                                <option value='@physicalAvailibility.PAId' selected='@(physicalAvailibility.PAId == @inventorydata.PAId)'>@physicalAvailibility.PhysicalAvailbilityType </option>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <option value='@physicalAvailibility.PAId'> @physicalAvailibility.PhysicalAvailbilityType </option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="selectpicker" title="Select" name="ddlRack" id="ddlrack__@inventorydata.TranId">
                                        @foreach (var rACK in Model.racks)
                                        {
                                            if (@inventorydata.RKID != 0)
                                            {
                                                <option value='@rACK.RkId' selected='@(rACK.RkId == @inventorydata.RKID)'>@rACK.RkName </option>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <option value='@rACK.RkId'> @rACK.RkName </option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="selectpicker" title="Select" name="ddlShelf" id="ddlshelf_@inventorydata.TranId">
                                        @foreach (var sHELF in Model.shelfes)
                                        {
                                            if (@inventorydata.SHELFID != 0)
                                            {
                                                <option value='@sHELF.ShelfId' selected='@(sHELF.ShelfId == @inventorydata.SHELFID)'>@sHELF.ShelfName </option>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <option value='@sHELF.ShelfId'> @sHELF.ShelfName </option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="Damages1"></label>
                                    <select class="selectpicker" title="Select" name="ddlPhysiclCondition" id="ddlpc_@inventorydata.TranId">
                                        @foreach (var cONDITION in Model.physical_conditions)
                                        {
                                            if (@inventorydata.PCID != 0)
                                            {
                                                <option value='@cONDITION.PCID' selected='@(cONDITION.PCID == @inventorydata.PCID)'>@cONDITION.PHYSICALCONDITION </option>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <option value='@cONDITION.PCID'> @cONDITION.PHYSICALCONDITION </option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group ds-input-with-icon customTextaria">
                                        <textarea class="form-control textwrite1" name="txtRemark" placeholder="Type here" rows="" cols="" maxlength="">@inventorydata.Remark</textarea>
                                        <div class="waves-block waves-block1 d-none">
                                            <div class="waves wave-1"></div>
                                            <div class="waves wave-2"></div>
                                            <div class="waves wave-3"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn mice-btn mice-btn1" aria-label="Name"><i class="hdr-mick"></i></button>
                                    </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!--Table with action link-->
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center btn-warp mt-16 cta-warp">
                <button onclick="resetAllControls();" type="button" id="btnInventoryclear" class="btn btn-secondary-outline ds-btn-ripple ds-btn-secondary-outline ds-btn-small">Cancel</button>
                <button id="btnInventorySave" type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline ds-btn-ripple ds-btn-primary-outline ds-btn-small">Save Draft</button>
                <button id="btnInventorySubmit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#success" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-ripple ds-btn-primary ds-btn-small">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</main>
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Inventory.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // var vvv = $("#withLine tbody tr:first").find("button").closest(".mice-btn1").attr("class");

    $("#withLine tbody tr").find("button").closest(".mice-btn1").each(function () {
        //var elm = (this);
        $(this).on('click', function (e) {
            //$(document).on('click', '#start-record-btn', function(){
            $('.waves-block1').toggleClass('d-none');
            $('.mice-btn1 .hdr-mick').toggleClass('active');
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $('#start-record-btn1').removeClass('active');
            $('.brderVisited1').removeClass('visited');
            $("#next").removeClass("disabled");
            if (noteContent.length) {
                noteContent += ' ';
            }

            $('.circle-ripple').hide();
            recognition.stop();

            // setTimeout(function(){
            //   $('.circle-ripple').hide();
            //   recognition.stop();
            //   $('.microphone_T').removeClass('active');
            //   $('.textAreaBorder').removeClass('visited');
            //  }, 3000);

            recognition.start();

            // $('#start-record-btn').fadeOut();
            // $('#pause-record-btn').fadeIn();

        });
    })

    $(document).ready(function () {

        debugger;
        $(document).on("change", ".checkAll1", function () {
            $(".check1").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
        });
        $(document).on("change", ".check1", function () {
            debugger;
            if (false === $(this).prop("checked")) {
                $(".checkAll1").prop('checked', false);
            }
            if ($('.check1:checked').length === $('.check1').length) {
                $(".checkAll1").prop('checked', true);
            }
        });

        $(document).on("change", ".checkAll2", function () {
            $(".check2").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
        });
        $(document).on("change", ".check2", function () {
            if (false === $(this).prop("checked")) {
                $(".checkAll1").prop('checked', false);
            }
            if ($('.check2:checked').length === $('.check2').length) {
                $(".checkAll2").prop('checked', true);
            }
        });

        $(".check22").change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('#output').html('Yse');
            }
            else {
                $('#output').html('No');

            }
        });
        $('#withLine').DataTable({
            ordering: true,
            container: 'body',
            responsive: true,
            serverSide: false,
            
            dom: 'tipl',
            oLanguage: {
                oPaginate: {
                    sNext: "<i class='pg-icon icon-Arrowright2fill'></i>",
                    sPrevious: "<i class='pg-icon icon-Arrowleft2'></i>"
                },
            },
            language: {
                sLengthMenu: "_MENU_"
            },
            'columnDefs': [{
                'targets': [0, "desc", 6], // column index (start from 0)
                'orderable': false, // set orderable false for selected columns
            }]
        });
    });</script>
```

```
Inventory.js----
$(document).ready(function () {
    //#region This  will be called on button click to save inventory form data
    $("#btnInventorySave").click(function (e) {
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        var inventoryInfos = [];
        var i = 0;
        //loop through all checked checkbox.
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function (index, item) {
            //get current row
            i = i + 1;
            var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
            //define an object to store the inventory information.
            var InventoryInfo = new Object();

            //using find method to find element from current row, and then get the value.

            InventoryInfo.IsVerified = $(tr).find("input[name='checkedId']").val();
            InventoryInfo.AssetId = $(tr).find("input[name='hdnAssetId']").val();
            InventoryInfo.TranId = $(tr).find("input[name='hdnTranId']").val();
            InventoryInfo.MacUserId = $(tr).find("input[name='hdnMacUserId']").val();
            InventoryInfo.HygeineId = $(tr).find("input[name='hdnHygeineId']").val();
            InventoryInfo.ActionType = 1;
            InventoryInfo.PAId = $(tr).find("select[name='ddlphysicalctivity']").val();
            InventoryInfo.RKID = $(tr).find("select[name='ddlRack']").val();
            InventoryInfo.SHELFID = $(tr).find("select[name='ddlShelf']").val();
            InventoryInfo.PCID = $(tr).find("select[name='ddlPhysiclCondition']").val();
            InventoryInfo.Remark = $(tr).find("input[name='txtRemark']").val();
            //use the same method to get all the required values.
            inventoryInfos.push(InventoryInfo);
        });
        alert(i);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
            url: "/ManageStock/SaveInventoryDetails", // Controller/View
            data: { inventoryInfos },
            //dataType: 'json',
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                alert(true);

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(false);

            }

        });
    });
    //#endregion
    //#region This  will be called on button click to Submit inventory form data
    $("#btnInventorySubmit").click(function (e) {
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        if (IsValidateInventoryForm() == false) {
            debugger;
            alert("Please fill all fields of checked row.");
            return;
        }
        else {
            var inventoryInfos = [];

            //loop through all checked checkbox.
            $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function (index, item) {
                //get current row

                var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
                //define an object to store the inventory information.
                var InventoryInfo = new Object();

                //using find method to find element from current row, and then get the value.

                InventoryInfo.IsVerified = $(tr).find("input[name='checkedId']").val();
                InventoryInfo.AssetId = $(tr).find("input[name='hdnAssetId']").val();
                InventoryInfo.TranId = $(tr).find("input[name='hdnTranId']").val();
                InventoryInfo.MacUserId = $(tr).find("input[name='hdnMacUserId']").val();
                InventoryInfo.HygeineId = $(tr).find("input[name='hdnHygeineId']").val();
                InventoryInfo.ActionType = 2;
                InventoryInfo.PAId = $(tr).find("select[name='ddlphysicalctivity']").val();
                InventoryInfo.RKID = $(tr).find("select[name='ddlRack']").val();
                InventoryInfo.SHELFID = $(tr).find("select[name='ddlShelf']").val();
                InventoryInfo.PCID = $(tr).find("select[name='ddlPhysiclCondition']").val();
                InventoryInfo.Remark = $(tr).find("textarea[name='txtRemark']").val();
                //use the same method to get all the required values.
                inventoryInfos.push(InventoryInfo);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: "/ManageStock/SaveInventoryDetails", // Controller/View
                data: { inventoryInfos },
                //dataType: 'json',
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    alert(true);

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(false);

                }

            });
        }
    });
    //#endregion
});

// #region check Inventory form validation
function IsValidateInventoryForm() {
    debugger;
    var i = 0;
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function (index, item) {
        //get current row

        var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
        if ($(tr).find("select[name='ddlphysicalctivity']").val() == 0 || $(tr).find("select[name='ddlphysicalctivity']").val() == undefined) {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if ($(tr).find("select[name='ddlRack']").val() == 0 || $(tr).find("select[name='ddlRack']").val() == undefined) {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if ($(tr).find("select[name='ddlShelf']").val() == 0 || $(tr).find("select[name='ddlShelf']").val() == undefined) {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if ($(tr).find("select[name='ddlPhysiclCondition']").val() == 0 || $(tr).find("select[name='ddlPhysiclCondition']").val() == undefined) {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if ($(tr).find("textarea[name='txtRemark']").val() == "" || $(tr).find("textarea[name='txtRemark']").val() == undefined) {
            i = i + 1;
        }


    });
    if (i > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
// #endregion
// #region Clear the form data

function resetAllControls() {
    location.reload();
};

// #endregion
```

---

```
controller-----
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult InventoryVerify()
        {
            try
            {
                string LOGEDUSER = null;
                string UserRole = null;

                LOGEDUSER = "51813947";
                UserRole = "MAC User";
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LOGEDUSER))
                {
                    return Redirect("https://www.myhcl.com");
                }
                ParameterMacUserStockInfo param = new ParameterMacUserStockInfo();
                param.UserId = LOGEDUSER;
                param.Role = UserRole;
                param.ActionDate = DateTime.Now;
                param.ActionType = 1;
                InventoryVerifyInfo inventoryVerifyInfo = new InventoryVerifyInfo();
                inventoryVerifyInfo = _visitedStoreInfo.GetInventoryVerifyInfo(param);
                return View(inventoryVerifyInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception EX)
            {
                return View("/Views/Error.cshtml");

            }

        }
```

[First page on load time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irC1k.png)
[when click on next page dropdown no showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsRqs.png)

When i click on next page,and do sorting html dynamic drop will present as present on first page as first time